# How to get HTTP response out of async Function

Tags: c#, http, get, request, response

Hello I am trying to get the content of the HTTP response outside of this async function but can't return it because it is async. What should I do?

Here is the function:

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetResponse(string url)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false))
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            return response;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't access `Result`, it will block the thread; use `await` instead:

```
Console.WriteLine(await content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

To access the content outside the method:

```
var response = await GetResponse("url");
using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
{
    var contentString = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

If you are returning the response, make sure you don't wrap it in a `using` block, or else it will be disposed before you have chance to read the content:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetResponse(string url)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        return await client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Or alternatively return the content directly from the method:

```
public async Task<string> GetContentAsync(string url)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false))
    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
    {
        return await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: My problem is that when I try to display the content I get 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]' instead of the string that should be in the response (the HTML or the JSON if I want) so how can I solve this because I need to see what I am working with

Comment: @CSE_Random You must have missed an `await` e.g. `string content = await GetContentAsync("url");`